Dark Theme Toggle Button Code Not Working?
My code, shown below, for a dark theme toggle button isn't working; Visual Studio Code isn't telling me I have any errors. Can someone help me figure out what the issue is?


document.getElementById('themeButton').addEventListener('click'),
  function() { /* Theme button script */
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
  }
body {
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  color: black;
  h1 {
    color: rgb(63, 66, 145);
    /* Header 1 features */
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* Header 2 features */
    margin: 10px;
  }
  p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* Paragraph features */
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  /* Dark theme styles */
  .dark-theme {
    background-color: #A9a9a9;
    /* Dark gray background */
    color: #F5F5F5/* Light gray body text */
  }
  .dark-theme h1 {
    color: rgb(170, 172, 244)/* Light blue text for header 1 */
  }
}
<h1>Basic Website</h1>
<!-- Site text content -->
<hr>
<h2>Welcome to my basic webpage.</h2>
<p>This isn't my first time coding, but it's been so long that it might as well be.</p>

<img src="treehouse.jpg" alt="An elaborate treehouse.">
<!-- Image -->
<hr>

<button id="themeButton">Change Theme Color</button>
<!-- Theme button -->



The button should change the background to a dark gray, and the text should become light gray, but the button changes nothing when clicked.

Are there any errors in your dev console? Hint: check the documentation for addEventListener.

My debug console and the documentation doesn't show any problems, unless there's another way to check?

addEventListener() requires at least two arguments; you are supplying one, "click".

So should I use something other than addEventListener() or would I need to add another click argument?

Per the documentation, your function should be the second argument.

You have an error here

document.getElementById('themeButton').addEventListener('click'), function() { /* Theme button script */
document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
}

You must pass the function as the second argument to addEventListener, like this
document.getElementById('themeButton').addEventListener('click', function() { /* Theme button script */
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
});

You also have to move your .dark-theme CSS rules outside of body, because if you use it like in your example, it can only affect body's children, not body itself.
body {
    /* Main body styles */
}
/* Dark theme styles */
.dark-theme {
 
}


Thank you for catching that. However, I changed it like you showed here, and the button still doesn't work.

@m00nbugs you should also move .dark-theme CSS selector rules outside of body selector, as it can not affect the selector itself, only it's children when used like in your example. I've updated the answer.

I finally got it, thanks so much for your help!

(Two examples ahead!)
You need to reference the self body using & in Nested CSS since you actually toggle that class on the body element using document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
body {
  /* Default body styles */
  &.dark-theme {      /* alias for: body.dark-theme */
    /* Dark theme body styles */
  }
}

Then, for the H1 you can use: H1 being descendant of dark theme body class like:
h1 {
  /* Default h1 styles */
  .dark-theme & {     /* alias for: .dark-theme h1 */
    /* Dark theme h1 styles */
  }
}

and same as above h1 styles you can style any other selector.
Also, your JS had a typo; all fixed in the following example:


document.querySelector("#theme").addEventListener("click", () => { 
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
});
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  
  &.dark-theme {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

a {
  color: #0bf;
  
  .dark-theme & {
    color: #fb0;
  }
}
<button type="button" id="theme">Toggle theme</button>

<h1>TITLE</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#">dolor</a> sit amet.</p>




I frankly would not bother creating any buttons to toggle anything. Less UI the better, and it's 2024. and dark themes are pretty common in UI design. Instead, I would focus on the User's desired OS preferred theme using the @media prefers-color-scheme and some CSS properties:


:root {
  --accent: #0bf;
  --color: #333;
  --bg: #fff;
  
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    --accent: #0bf;
    --color: #fff;
    --bg: #333;
  }
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  color: var(--color);
}

a {
  color: var(--accent);
}
<h1>TITLE</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#">dolor</a> sit amet.</p>




Thanks but it's just for a basic coding assignment.

@m00nbugs You're welcome! And I gave you a trivial CSS solution as well. Perfect for basic coding assignments.
